# NoClassDefFoundError com/google/inject/Injector when running simple Neo4J test

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to get up and running writing an embedded Neo4J Java 1.8 application. I'm following the developer's manual and attempting to run a simple test to initialize a local test DB:

```
 @Test
 public void initNeo4J() {
     graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
 }
```

I'm seeing a runtime exception with the root cause of:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Injector
```

If I add Google Guice to the classpath, this error goes away and everything works fine. However, I don't see this dependency documented anywhere so I feel like I'm missing something or doing something wrong. Is this just an undocumented dependency or have I missed a critical dependency that pulls the injector in? Here are my current dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
 </dependency>
```

**EDIT, Here's the full stack trace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory$1$1, C:\project\socialalpha\socialalpha-spark\neo4j-dev\target\test-data\impermanent-db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(TestGraphDatabaseFactory.java:232)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory.newImpermanentDatabase(TestGraphDatabaseFactory.java:60)
    at com.sa.TestNeo4J.initNeo4J(TestNeo4J.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeBeforeGroupsConfigurations(Invoker.java:857)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:581)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Neo4jJobScheduler@5629510' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Injector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.DebugUtil.trackTest(DebugUtil.java:300)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Neo4jJobScheduler.init(Neo4jJobScheduler.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Injector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: I wonder if you're using maven correctly. [Maven doesn't automatically build an executable jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425453/maven-build-with-dependencies).

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in Neo4j.

Temporarily, you can add Guice:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

An official fix will come soon, you can follow the [issue #10722](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10722).

For more information: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10722#issuecomment-374417890

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I realized that this was due to other conflicts on the classpath, most likely an older/newer version of Google Guava.